# jQuery - adding more stuff to object

Tags: jquery

I got this object:

```
currentid = 123;

    $.extend(artikel,{
        [currentid]:{"pfostenanzahl": pfostenanzahl,
        "pfostenart": "T&uuml;rpfosten",
        "pfostenfarbe": farbe,
        "pfostenmass": pfostenmasse + 'x' + pfostenlaenge,
        "befestigung": befestigung,
        "gesamtlaenge": gesamtlaenge,
        "pfostenkosten": pfostenkosten,
        "pfostenlaenge": pfostenlaenge}
    });
```

And I just want to add

```
$.extend(artikel,{
    [currentid]:{"gesamtbetrag": gesamtbetrag}
});
```

But everything which was added first time just disappears.
How to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the version that does [deep](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) merging.

So pass `true` as the first argument.

```
$.extend(true, artikel,{
    [currentid]:{"gesamtbetrag": gesamtbetrag}
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I already found another way:         $.extend(artikel[currentid],{
            "gesamtbetrag": gesamtbetrag
        }); but I will go with your solution

Comment: @EddyUnruh yes that would work too, unless a property in the `[currentid]` also held an object.